# mallet topic modling: How to deactive lowercase?

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

I'm conducting an topic modeling experiment with Mallet on german texts. Since german nouns begin with uppercase, I want to keep this feature. Does anyone know how to deactivate lowercasing?

Answer (score 1):

Add `--preserve-case` when importing documents.